# Prevent dired-find-alternate-file from killing emacsclient

Tags: dired, emacsclient

When visiting a folder with emacsclient, for example through `emacsclient .`, using dired, opening a folder using `a` will cause emacsclient to terminate. I believe this is because `a`, bound to `dired-find-alternate-file` will close the buffer emacsclient is in some way bound to causing it to terminate. I observe the same behavior when using `dired-single.el`.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Given my above assumptions about how why this happens: to make dired reuse the same buffer rather than destroy it?

Comment: `dired-find-alternate-file`'s doc string says: `In Dired, visit file or directory on current line via ‘find-alternate-file’.
This kills the Dired buffer, then visits the current line’s file or directory.` So it seems to me that the only way to avoid the problem is to avoid using `dired-find-alternate-file`. What's wrong with `dired-find-file` (bound to `f`)? It leaves the directory buffer alone, so emacsclient can continue enjoying its existence.

Comment: I would prefer to not fill upp my buffer list with a lot of dired buffers I will never use again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remap `dired-find-alternate-file` to a custom command which firstly checks to see whether `server-buffer-clients` is non-`nil` in that dired buffer.  If it's `nil` then just go ahead and call `dired-find-alternate-file`; if it's set, then work around the issue...

Some possible workarounds are:

1. Call `dired-find-file` instead of `dired-find-alternate-file`.  Maybe `bury-buffer` for the original buffer, too.
2. Set the buffer-local `server-buffer-clients` to `nil`.  This will prevent `server-kill-buffer` from killing every client for which this was the sole remaining buffer of interest.  It means there will be a stale entry in the `buffers` list for the client process -- but `server-buffer-done` already copes with dead buffers, so it's basically fine.

   Or similar: remove the buffer-local `kill-buffer-hook` entry `server-kill-buffer` in that buffer.

   Either way, when the dired buffer is killed, the client stays alive.

   That sounds good, but probably isn't actually sufficient.  In the case you're interested in -- the one where that client in reality has *no* live buffers of interest after that dired buffer has been killed -- then that client is going to be killed the next time that *any* client-buffer (for any client) is killed -- so you might still lose the client without meaning to.
3. That all being the case, I think instead of using (2), your custom command would be better to call `server-visit-files` for the file you're asking dired to open, in order that the new buffer can be registered for the client (in practice you probably need to do this for *every* client which was interested in the original buffer).  Then you're effectively shifting the client's interest from buffer to buffer, but it's not subject to sudden death on account of some other client.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as this annoyance is not going away, I thought people might appreciate a code solution. My approach is to write alternatives to `find-alternate-file` and `dired-find-alternate-file`.

```el
(defun my-find-alternate-file (newfile)
  "switch to new file, then kill old buffer"
  (remove-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'server-kill-buffer t)
  (let ((my-old-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (find-file newfile)
    (kill-buffer my-old-buffer)))

(defun my-dired-find-alternate-file ()
  "open a new file from dired, then kill the old dired buffer"
  (interactive)
  (my-find-alternate-file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
```

Uses @phils second approach and seems to be working for me.

=== edit ===

By the way, as of 28 you are supposed to be able to set `dired-kill-when-opening-new-dired-buffer` to get this same effect, but it only seems to works intermittently--most of the time you end up with an ever-expanding list of dired buffers.

Comment: @phils Thanks. This was actually a simplification of my real function (which also tracks the position you were at in the previous buffer) and I didn't test. I tried the current version and it should be ok. Sorry about that.

Comment: I would `M-x report-emacs-bug` if `dired-kill-when-opening-new-dired-buffer` is not working as advertised (and, ideally, you can suggest a way to reproduce the issue from `emacs -Q`).

Comment: `(interactive)` with no args doesn't mesh with having a required arg `(newfile)` for interactive use.  You could make the argument optional and use `(call-interactively 'find-file)` instead of `(find-file newfile)` if it wasn't supplied.  Alternatively, if you *only* expect to use `my-dired-find-alternate-file` then `my-find-alternate-file` needn't be interactive at all.

Comment: @phils Thanks. I'll take a look. I'm new to elisp...lots to learn. I'm not 100% clear on when functions need to be marked as interactive. A lambda with (my-find-alternate-file "..") is bound to h in my setup, so thought I needed it, but I just tried without and it worked. Lots to learn.

Comment: In that instance your lambda function presumably includes `(interactive)`?  It is only necessary for the function which is being bound to the key sequence to be interactive (otherwise more or less *every* function would need to be interactive).

Comment: For clarity, functions need to be `interactive` to be a "command" -- meaning you can directly bind them to a key sequence or call them by name with `M-x`.  If neither of those things are required, then (for the most part) there's no reason to make them interactive.  The `interactive` spec for a function also declares how the function's arguments (if any) will be obtained when the function is being invoked in those ways.

Comment: @phils That's exactly right. My lambda function had it, so I guess that is all that was needed. Thanks for helping me out!